Aurelia : if.bind or repeat.for with a parameter
The .ts file of my Aurelia component generates arrays of composed elements to render :
private getComposedElements(panelIndex: number): ComposedElement[] {
    return this.panels[panelIndex].map(element => toComposedElement(element));
}

In an ideal world, the .html then would render them like this :
<!-- All elements of panel 0 -->
<template repeat.for="item of getComposedElements(0)">
    <compose containerless view-model.bind="item">
    </compose>
</template>

<!-- All elements of panel 1 -->
<template repeat.for="item of getComposedElements(1)">
    <compose containerless view-model.bind="item">
    </compose>
</template>

<!-- All elements of panel 2 -->
<template repeat.for="item of getComposedElements(2)">
    <compose containerless view-model.bind="item">
    </compose>
</template>

...

(note that I could also have used a repeat.for for all panels in an outer loop, but I wanted to ask my question in a more readable manner)
Problem : the code above doesn't work, because I need the render to be recomputed when this.panels changes. Normally I would simply add @computedFrom just above getComposedElements but it doesn't work because that annotation only works with getters (i.e. : no 'panelIndex' parameter allowed!)
So instead I did this :
    @computedFrom("panels")  // or panels.length if that makes you sleep better
    public get getComposedElements0(): ComposedElement[]  {
        return this.getComposedElements(0);
    }

    @computedFrom("panels")
    public get getComposedElements1(): ComposedElement[]  {
        return this.getComposedElements(1);
    }

    ...

    private getComposedElements(panelIndex: number): ComposedElement[] {
        return this.panels[panelIndex].map(element => toComposedElement(element));
    }

.html
 <!-- All elements of panel 0 -->
    <template repeat.for="item of getComposedElements0">
        <compose containerless view-model.bind="item">
        </compose>
    </template>

    <!-- All elements of panel 1 -->
    <template repeat.for="item of getComposedElements1">
        <compose containerless view-model.bind="item">
        </compose>
    </template>

    ...

It works but it is horrible. It would be insane to create as many getComposedElementsXXX getters as there are panels.
I thought the simplest solution might be to get rid of method getComposedElements entirely and instead do something like this, directly in the .html:
    <template repeat.for="item of panels[0].map(element => toComposedElement(element))">
        <compose containerless view-model.bind="item">
        </compose>
    </template>

    <template repeat.for="item of panels[1].map(element => toComposedElement(element))">
        <compose containerless view-model.bind="item">
        </compose>
    </template>

    ...

Sadly, Aurelia does not allow complex syntax inside repeat.for. The compiler complains about => or other symbols like !! or whatnot.
So what's the solution here? If I start making the panels composed components too, then the amount of boilerplate code will explode to pass bindables up and down. Plus, I will probably fail as I barely understand what I'm doing with Aurelia.
